# CSS issue with ::before on phones

Tags: html, css, web, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I met small problem when using ::before... I`m adding small triangle before my div content to make it more fancy, i have animated background and i found that on low resolutions (specialy on phones) there are some weird lines that i cant get rid off.

here is my code

```
#thirdScreen::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 90vw 0 10vw;
  border-color: transparent #E3E3E3 ;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/kW6O6ozGQnqzm/giphy.gif);
  background-size: contain;
}
```

and here is what i see when I`m inspecting it as a phone:
[inspect with Galaxy S5 360x640](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9qpK.jpg)

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWmWEL

If someone can tell me what can i do with it will be very helpfull.
Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend re-creating in jsfiddle or codepen, or as a Stack Snippet so that potential answerers can easily see the problem.

Comment: Adding codepen in post, not sure if everything is good (i see there are small difference in bootstrap) but im sure that you can see this issue when inspecting this codepen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about rendering. Triangle you creating in `::before` is hovering your section just on same pixels from the top, in some resolutions you may be able to see one-pixel difference, that why there is the border. Solution for this is to add simply margin-top: -1px;

```
#secondScreen::before {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```